Proof by induction that the number of t$
Let $l,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and define $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $i\in [l]$. I need to express the number of tuples  such that $ 1\leq a_1\leq ...\leq a_l\leq n$.
I know that this number is $n+l-1 \choose l$.
I'm trying to find a proof of this theorem using only induction.
If $n=1$ then we have only one tuple that works.
So let's proof it for $n+1$. We can consider to disjoint cases. There are tuples with $a_i \leq n     \forall                i\in [l]$ and cases in which at least one $a_i=n+1$.
I'm not sure if this casework helps me. Could this lead to a solution or is this approach useless?

What's $k$?  Did you mean to write $k-$tuples?   If so, this is just Stars and Bars, which has been written up extensively.

@lulu Yes I know about this way to proof it but I search for a proof by induction. Sorry, there should be a l.

I think you're on the right track, but you need to split the possibilities into more cases. Consider your problem for $l$ and $n+1$. How many ways are there of choosing $a_1, \dots, a_l$ such that exactly $k$ of the values are smaller than $n+1$? By induction (on both $l$ and $n$) this number is equal to $\binom{n+k-1}k$. Therefore, the total number of possibilities is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^l \binom{n+k-1}k$.
Thus, we need to prove that
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=0}^l \binom{n+k-1}k = \binom{n+l}l.
\end{equation}
This can again be done by induction on $l$. The formula is trivial for $l = 0$. Now suppose that the formula holds for $l-1$. Then we get that
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=0}^l \binom{n+k-1}k = \sum_{k=0}^{l-1} \binom{n+k-1}k + \binom{n+l-1}l = \binom{n+l-1}{l-1} + \binom{n+l-1}l.
\end{equation}
The right hand side is equal to $\binom{n+l}l$ by Pascal's identity.
